# Chrome Content Script doesn't run when inspecting WebView for Android Emulator

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-emulator, console, content-script

I have a Chrome Content Script setup to match `<all_urls>`. It runs when I load any website or local file in the browser. But I can't figure out how to get it to run when I'm inspecting a WebView from the Android Emulator which I'm accessing via chrome://inspect/#devices.

Is it possible for Content Scripts to load when inspecting a device WebView like this?

Comment: As far as I know. Content scripts is dependent on browser that is running in. When you inspect the device. It's debugging remotely the browser on the mobile. It's different than you PC browser which has content script.

Comment: @AraYeressian - Ah, of course. So what I would need is a Content Script running in the mobile browser, which as of now I don't believe is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question. It's not possible because the Content Script I've written is running in the desktop browser, whereas the app I'm inspecting is in the device browser - two totally different environments. I would need a Content Script in the device browser, but the mobile Chrome browser doesn't support this as of now.